# NullPointerException using constructor of `File` class (only on Samsung A series devices) in my application

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception, google-play-console

I have an application published on the Play Store (Google Play). For months now, I have been receiving an error in my console. First of all, here is the relevant code from my application:

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
    //more code

    //get storage directories
    rutasTemp = getStorageDirectoriesWithoutNull(this);
    int indexTemp = 0;
    for (String s : rutasTemp) {
        if (!(s.contains("usb"))) {
            indexTemp++;
        }
    }
    if (externalMemoryAvailable(this)) {
        rutas = new String[indexTemp];
        indexTemp = 0;
        for (String s : rutasTemp) {
            if (!(s.contains("usb"))) {
                rutas[indexTemp] = s;
                indexTemp++;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<rutas.length; i++) {
            if (rutas[i].contains("emulated")) {
                String temp = rutas[0];
                rutas[0] = rutas[i];
                rutas[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    } else {
        rutas = new String[1];
        rutas[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/";

    }

    //more code

    carpetasPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_CARPETAS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}


private void prepararPlayer(int desdeDonde) {

    //more code

    Map<String, ?> carpetasMap = carpetasPreferences.getAll();
    String[] carpetasArray = null;
    carpetasArray = new String[carpetasMap.size()];
    int indice = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> asno: carpetasMap.entrySet()) {
        carpetasArray[indice] = asno.getValue().toString() + "/";
        indice++;
    }
    if (carpetasMap.size() == 0) {
        if (notClickedOnce) {
            carpetasArray = new String[rutas.length];
            //button pressed first time
            carpetasArray[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Music/";
            if (rutas.length > 1) {
                carpetasArray[1] = rutas[1];
            }
        }
    }

    if (desdeDonde == 0) {
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(LIST_OF_FILES)) {
            nombresArchivo = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(LIST_OF_FILES, new HashSet<String>());
        } else {
            buscarArchivos = new BuscarArchivos(this, carpetasArray, nombresArchivo, desdeDonde);
            buscarArchivos.execute();
        }
    } else {
        buscarArchivos = new BuscarArchivos(this, carpetasArray, nombresArchivo, desdeDonde);
        buscarArchivos.execute();
    }
        
    //more code
}


private static class BuscarArchivos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;
    String[] carpetasArray;
    Set<String> nombArch;
    int desdeDonde;
    BuscarArchivos(MainActivity activity, String[] carpetasArray, Set<String> nombresArchivo, 
        int desdeDonde) {
            this.activityReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
            this.carpetasArray = carpetasArray;
            this.nombArch = nombresArchivo;
            this.desdeDonde = desdeDonde;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            for (String asn : carpetasArray) {
                activityReference.get().listAllFiles(asn, nombArch);
            }                   
            activityReference.get().sharedPreferencesEditor
                .putStringSet(activityReference.get()
                .LIST_OF_FILES, nombArch);
            activityReference.get().sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            return writer.toString();
        }
        return "final";
    }
        
    //rest of the code of BuscarArchivos
}

public void listAllFiles(String rutaAdentro, Set<String> archivos) {
    File file = new File(rutaAdentro);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File asno : files) {
            if (asno.isFile()) {
                archivos.add(asno.getName());
            } else if (asno.isDirectory()) {
                listAllFiles(asno.getAbsolutePath(), archivos);
            }
        }
    }
}

private String[] getStorageDirectoriesWithoutNull(Context context) {
    String[] allDirectories = StorageUtil
        .getStorageDirectories(context);
    ArrayList<String> directoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String directory : allDirectories) {
        if (directory != null) {
            directoriesList.add(directory);
        }
    }
    return directoriesList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

I'm using the library StorageUtil by hendrawd (https://github.com/hendrawd/StorageUtil) in the `getStorageDirectoriesWithoutNull` method.

The following is the adapter used in the activity in which a select music folders:

**Adapter**

```
public Adaptador(Context contextInside, int layoutIdInside, ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
    String>> listaInside, String rutaInside) {

        //more code
        
        carpetasPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_CARPETAS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        carpetasPreferencesEditor = carpetasPreferences.edit();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //more code

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                carpetasPreferencesEditor.putString(elemento.get(PATH), elemento.get(PATH));
                carpetasPreferencesEditor.apply();
            } else {
                if (carpetasPreferences.contains(elemento.get(PATH))) {
                    carpetasPreferencesEditor.remove(elemento.get(PATH));
                    carpetasPreferencesEditor.apply();
                }
            }
            if (carpetasPreferences.contains(ruta)) {
                carpetasPreferencesEditor.remove(ruta);
                carpetasPreferencesEditor.apply();
            }
        }
    });
       
    //rest of the code
}
```

I hope I've included all the relevant code. If I've forgotten something, I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

I'm having the following error in my google play console:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:283)
    at gym.timer.app.MainActivity.listAllFiles(MainActivity.java:3093)
    at gym.timer.app.MainActivity$BuscarArchivos.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:3133)
    at gym.timer.app.MainActivity$BuscarArchivos.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:3118)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

As you can see, I'm having a NullPointerException in the line: `File[] files = file.listFiles();`.
The application works well on almost all devices, but I am experiencing errors on a few devices, specifically/only on Samsung A series devices. Below, I list the models of the devices:

error SM-A217M sdk 31
error SM-A127M sdk 30
error SM-A305G sdk 30
error SM-A505G sdk 30
error SM-A307G sdk 30
error SM-A505G sdk 30
error SM-A105M sdk 30
error SM-A307G sdk 29
error SM-A305G sdk 30
error SM-A217F sdk 30
error SM-A127M sdk 33

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

I bought a smartphone, specifically the 'SM-A307G,' which is one of the models where the error appears, just to be able to reproduce the error. I formatted it, installed the application, but no error appears; it works normally. What I wanted was to reproduce the error, but no error appeared.

Comment: Your error is in the constructor of class `java.io.File`. Looks like you are passing a null parameter when you call the constructor, i.e. `rutaAdentro` is null - which means that `carpetasArray` contains a null. So I suggest that you debug your code and try to discover why an element in `carpetasArray` is null. Hint: all elements in an array are implicitly initialized to null. How are you assigning a value to `carpetasArray`? Are you doing `new String[]`?

Comment: This `if` statement (in method `prepararPlayer` of `MainActivity`) may be the problem: `if (rutas.length > 1) {`. My guess is that `rutas[1]` is null.

Comment: @Abra Yes, I'm using: `carpetasArray = new String[carpetasMap.size()]`. Is in the code.

Comment: @Abra I added the relevant code for `rutas` which is inside the method `onCreate`, and the method `getStorageDirectoriesWithoutNull` in which I'm using the library StorageUtil by hendrawd (https://github.com/hendrawd/StorageUtil).

Comment: This is ***not*** a "`NullPointerException` using method `listFiles` of `File` class". The exception is in the *constructor * of `File`. You haven't called `listFiles()` yet. Read the stack trace.

Comment: I can't see the point of your title edit. Best to identify the actual problem in the title. Rather than just waffle. Reverted.

Comment: I think this information is useful for other developers experiencing a similar error on those devices.

Comment: @user207421 I never put the title: "NullPointerException using method listFiles of File class" that you mention. Read again.

Comment: It is entirely irrelevant that your app is published in Google Play.

Comment: You're right. Do as you please with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File one param constructors throws NPE when called with `null`

```java
    public File(String pathname) {
        if (pathname == null) {
            // your initial error
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
        this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
    }
```

The error stacktrace doesnt show any recursive call so the error came from initial call to the function

```java
for (String asn : carpetasArray) {
    activityReference.get().listAllFiles(asn, nombArch);
}
```

So you may have one `null` value in your `carpetasArray`

IMHO, the following code could produce `null` values in this array

```java
if (notClickedOnce) {
    // possible null values here if rutas.length > 2, since you dont set carpetasArray indices higher than 1
    carpetasArray = new String[rutas.length];
    //button pressed first time
    carpetasArray[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Music/";
    if (rutas.length > 1) {
        // possible null value here if rutas[1] is null
        carpetasArray[1] = rutas[1];
    }
}
```

Since we have no idea from where `rutas` came from, my guess would be to look for the to above possibilities.
You can also protect your `listAllFiles` function to add something like

```java
public void listAllFiles(String rutaAdentro, Set<String> archivos) {
    if (rutaAdentro != null) {
        // only run the function if rutaAdentro is not null to avoid NPE on new File(null)
        File file = new File(rutaAdentro);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File asno : files) {
                if (asno.isFile()) {
                    archivos.add(asno.getName());
                } else if (asno.isDirectory()) {
                    listAllFiles(asno.getAbsolutePath(), archivos);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By doing so, you shouldnt have NPE anymore.

Comment: I added the relevant code for `rutas` which is inside the method `onCreate`, and the method `getStorageDirectoriesWithoutNull` in which I'm using the library StorageUtil by hendrawd (github.com/hendrawd/StorageUtil).

Comment: Ok so my guess is that `rutas.length > 2` and.you dont initialize the `index >=2` in your `carpetasArray` as pointed in my answer (possible null value comment added in your code snippet)

Comment: Okay. The error only occurs on Samsung A series devices. I have one of those models where the error appears; how could I reproduce the error to see if it has been fixed?.
Because I install the application on that device, but the error does not appear.

Comment: I dont know what function is trigger and what the goal is. To be sure code is fixed, the best way is to protect code in `listAllFiles` with sanity check that arg is not `null` before calling the `new File` function

Comment: That's a good point. But what do you think about: `carpetasArray = new String[rutas.length];
Arrays.fill(carpetasArray, "");`

Comment: Or: `List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(carpetasArray));
        lista.removeIf(elemento -> elemento == null);
        carpetasArray = lista.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Or: `                for (String asn : carpetasArray) {
                    if (asn != null) {
                        activityReference.get().listAllFiles(asn, nombArch);
                    }
                }`

Comment: What approach would be the best?

Comment: Well I dont think you want to call the function `listAllFiles` with empty string as it could lead to unexpected behaviour. Preventing the caller to call the function with illegal value (`null`) is a good start. But since you're doing recursive calls of the function, the best and simpliest option in my opinion would be to protect the function itself in order to run the code only if arg is not `null`

Comment: Updated answer for my view of `listAllFiles` function with added if based on your code to prevent NPE

Comment: You were right, the error was that the size of `rutas` was greater than 2 on Samsung A series devices. On those devices, there was a strange path being returned by the method.

Comment: I think this information is useful for other developers experiencing a similar error on those devices. But it seems the question has been closed.

Comment: Well NPE are common pb in java world but your question has been answered before closed so... hope everything will work as expected for you now :-)